# MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am very new to Ethereum smart contract solidity programming. Currently, I have been facing this issue when I try to pass a variable from my Node.js servlet to the smart contract I deployed using Truffle Suite, specifically with accounts provided by Ganache.

Following is the JavaScript I used to connect and call the smart contract method:

```
if (this.state.contract) {
            this.state.contract.methods.searchKeyword(searchToken.toString())
                .send({from: this.state.account, gas: 210000, gasPrice: 50000}, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error", err)
                        return
                    }
                    console.log(res)
                })
        }
```

Following is the Solidity code in smart contract:

```
function searchKeyword (string memory searchToken) public {
        searchWord = searchToken;
    }
```

Whenever I call the function and pass `searchToken` , the following error pops up. I have tried setting the gas and gasPrice over, within, below the gasLimit of my MetaMask wallet but I am still getting errors like `Exceeds block gas limit`. I have tried without setting the gas and gasPrice but I am still getting the similar issue.

[image]

Any genius please help me this noob beginner who trying so hard to debug just a small little function. Thank you guys in advance :D

Comment: I'm with the same error. You should try asking this question on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that when you "truffle deploy --reset", the Ganache blockchain expects the 'program_counter' of each user to start from 0 again. So you also have to start the program_counter over on your Metamask Account. Metamask Settings -> Advanced -> Reset Account restarts the program_counter for your Metamask accounts. This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try reseting your metamask accounts (settings > advanced > reset account). Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Im using hardhat and got this error when testing on localhost.
solution:

1. Make sure you are using chrome or brave browser.
2. Close the node you are running in the terminal (cntl+C)
3. Close you localhost server.
4. Restart VS code.
5. Startup a new node: npx hardhat node
6. In another terminal tab run your deployment scripts: npx hardhat run scripts/foo.js
7. Make sure your code is compiled in artifacts and you are using the correct address in your frontend code.
8. Restart localhost server and do the transaction again.